# How to exclude the Debug messages while shipping the logs using filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat, graylog

Hello i am trying to exclude the Debug logs while shipping the logs from my Azure kubernetes services using "filebeat"

I am trying with the below code but somehow its not working out

```
filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      exclude_lines: ['^DEBUG^']
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
```

I also tried adding drop_event but no luck:

```
processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
            - drop_event:
                when:
                  contains:
                    status: "^DEBUG:"
```

Complete code:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: log
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      exclude_lines: ['.*DEBUG.*']
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
```

Please correct me if am doing wrong.

Comment: The `^DEBUG^` regexp has two `^` (i.e. beginning of line marker) that's probably why it doesn't work. It should have [only one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log-exclude-lines) if your lines begin with `DEBUG`

Comment: @Val The line starts with the timestamp and later DEBUG, WARN, INFO shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If the line starts with a timestamp and then the log level, then you need to modify your regular expression accordingly, as `^DEBUG^` is not a valid regexp.

Just try this one:

```
exclude_lines: ['.*DEBUG.*']
```

Comment: I tried the above mentioned but it dint work, my log:

2023-04-25 13:02:46.696 DEFAULT [Xxxx-2 task-4] DEBUG

Comment: Yeah, maybe share a sample of your log

Comment: 2023-04-25 13:02:46.696 DEFAULT [Xxxx-2 task-4] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils [] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource

Comment: Try again with my updated answer

Comment: No luck its still the same. 2023-04-25 13:11:59.497 DEFAULT [Xxxx-2 task-7] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils [] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

Comment: Are you sure that those lines are coming from that input and not another one that lets everything through? Pretty simple regexp like in [many other examples](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-get-regex-to-exclude-line-to-work/95432)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253315/discussion-between-docgyan-and-val).

Comment: Could you start filebeat in debug mode (i.e. equivalent to `./filebeat -e -d "*"`) and share the logging output you get (maybe via gist)?